# Vagrant box import on other device

Tags: vagrant, development-environment, vagrantfile

I have a Vagrant box which is using the [Scotch box](https://box.scotch.io/) environment. I have had an other PC and I didn't have any provisioning because I did everything manually ssh into the box.

The question, how can I take this from my first PC to my second PC? I looked the `vagrant snapshot` command, but I think it is'nt what I want, because it's just take a save about the box current state, but don't save the whole environment to deploy it to another PC.

**Edit:**

I am using VirtualBox provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is [repackage](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/box.html#repackage) the current VM built on this box as a new box.

once you repackage the box, it will create a new `.box` file of your VM with all the changes you've made and you can copy this file to your second PC, add as a new box in your vagrant and spin a new VM from this box. All the changes you have made on the box from the first PC will be available.